# Android 8.0 can not open the wifi switch

Tags: android

When I turn on the wifi switch, the switch will automatically turn off. 
I don't know what caused it.

this is log

```
12-31 19:02:10.566 D/WifiService( 2139): setWifiEnabled: true pid=3201, uid=1000, package=com.android.tv.settings
12-31 19:02:10.629 D/WificondControl( 2139): wifiLoadDriver() in wificond
12-31 19:02:10.649 I/wificond( 1921): user don't need load driver
12-31 19:02:10.649 I/wificond( 1921): wifiLoadDriver flag=1
12-31 19:02:10.709 E/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service( 1889): Failed to initialize legacy hal function table
12-31 19:02:10.709 E/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service( 1889): Failed to initialize legacy HAL: NOT_SUPPORTED
12-31 19:02:10.713 I/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service( 1889): Wifi HAL started
12-31 19:02:10.733 E/HalDeviceManager( 2139): IWifiEventCallback.onFailure: 4 ()
12-31 19:02:10.733 E/HalDeviceManager( 2139): Cannot start IWifi: 4 ()
12-31 19:02:10.743 E/WifiNative-wlan0( 2139): Failed to start HAL for client mode
12-31 19:02:10.810 D/WificondControl( 2139): tearing down interfaces in wificond
12-31 19:02:10.813 I/WifiVendorHal( 2139): Vendor Hal stopped
12-31 19:02:10.813 D/WificondControl( 2139): wifiLoadDriver() in wificond
12-31 19:02:10.815 I/wificond( 1921): user don't need load driver
12-31 19:02:10.815 I/wificond( 1921): wifiLoadDriver flag=1
12-31 19:02:10.819 E/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service( 1889): Failed to initialize legacy hal function table
12-31 19:02:10.819 E/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service( 1889): Failed to initialize legacy HAL: NOT_SUPPORTED
12-31 19:02:10.819 I/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service( 1889): Wifi HAL started
12-31 19:02:10.820 E/HalDeviceManager( 2139): Cannot start IWifi: 4 ()
12-31 19:02:10.820 E/HalDeviceManager( 2139): IWifiEventCallback.onFailure: 4 ()
12-31 19:02:10.821 E/WifiNative-wlan0( 2139): Failed to start HAL for client mode
12-31 19:02:10.822 D/WificondControl( 2139): tearing down interfaces in wificond
12-31 19:02:10.825 I/WifiVendorHal( 2139): Vendor Hal stopped
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about programming.

Comment: I think it should be, it may be related to HAL, but I don’t know much about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you got this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

And create wifiManager  every time

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Comment: My problem is not the app problem, it is the system settings app, wifi can not be opened, so your solution may not work, but thank you